# abstractmethod is needed in python

Tags: python

What does the `abstractmethod decorator` in python does?

```py
from abc import abstractmethod

class Animal(object):   

    @abstractmethod
    def walk(self):
        ''' data '''
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def talk(self):
        ''' data '''
        pass

class Duck(Animal):
    name = ''

    def __init__(self, name):
        print('duck created.')
        self.name = name

    def walk(self):
        print('walks')

    def talk(self):
        print('quack')

obj = Duck('duck1')
obj.talk()
obj.walk()
```

But if I comment the decorator, the code still works.

```py
from abc import abstractmethod

class Animal(object):   

    def walk(self):
        ''' data '''
        pass

    def talk(self):
        ''' data '''
        pass

class Duck(Animal):
    name = ''

    def __init__(self, name):
        print('duck created.')
        self.name = name

    def walk(self):
        print('walks')

    def talk(self):
        print('quack')

obj = Duck('duck1')
obj.talk()
obj.walk()
```

My question is why bother to use this decorator? I even delete some of the methods in `Duck`, say `talk`. Then it does not crash. I makes me not understand when do we need to use this `abstractmethod`?

Comment: FWIW: https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does the abstractmethod decorator in python does?

What about [checking the doc ?](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod)

> A decorator indicating abstract methods.
>
> Using this decorator requires that the class’s metaclass is ABCMeta or
>   is derived from it. A class that has a metaclass derived from ABCMeta
>   cannot be instantiated unless all of its abstract methods and
>   properties are overridden.

Note that in your example the base `Animal` class doesn't use ABCMeta as it's metaclass so the decorator is mostly useless indeed.